# Can not config Tailwind in NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

i use `"@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^2.0.0"` for my Nuxt App.
After install, it created a tailwind.config.js file. And then, i added a little code as you could see below:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {},
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
  purge: {
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    content: [
      'components/**/*.vue',
      'layouts/**/*.vue',
      'pages/**/*.vue',
      'plugins/**/*.js',
      'nuxt.config.js',
    ],
  },
  options: {
    important: true,
  },
};
```

I want all the Tailwind's class have important, but it weren't.

[inside the tailwin's class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEfsX.png)

What i did wrong?

Comment: try setting purge.enabled = false, are you somehow running node_env production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what messed up.

So turn out that the problem was [PostCSS](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/configuration/#postcss-plugins)

And, another thing is that in older version, the important was in `options`, but now it placed at the root

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  important: true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are running `NODE_ENV=production` so its purging unused classes

Setting purge.enabled=false will do what you want. I don't recommend setting it false. If a class is used purge won't remove the class. As you are not using most of the classes in HTML they are getting removed.

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {},
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
  purge: {
    enabled: false, // DONT DO THIS IN PRODUCTION
    content: [
      'components/**/*.vue',
      'layouts/**/*.vue',
      'pages/**/*.vue',
      'plugins/**/*.js',
      'nuxt.config.js',
    ],
  },
  options: {
    important: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: i only kept `theme` and `options` but nothing happened, or change to false as you said but it still no important :( even i changed the default colors, nothing happened too

Comment: what is your nuxt configuration

Comment: `  tailwindcss: {
    configPath: './config/tailwind.config.js',
    cssPath: '~/assets/css/tailwind.css',
    exposeConfig: false,
  },`
this is tailwind config in my nuxt. Please check it :D
can you send me a mess at FB? my fb is fb.com/tranduybau . thank you 

Comment: sorry for being late. i found what i missed, this is postcss config:https://nuxtjs.org/faq/postcss-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

If I look at the documentation the important key should be at the root of export :

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  important: true,
}
```

instead of

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  options: {
    important: true,
  }
}
```